# Bounds on a rapidly increasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I read about a sequence similar to this one here on Stack Exchange a while back, somebody used it as an example for something that I can't recall! However, when I read about it it made me come up with this one, so here we are.

Let $\beta_n$ be the greatest number of the form $1/k$, with $k$ an integer, such that   $n | k$ and $\sum_{m=1}^n\beta_m \lt 1.$ i.e. $\beta_1=1/2, \beta_2=1/4, \beta_3=1/6$, etc.

I would like to put some bounds on the sequence $k_n=1/\beta_n$, or possibly even some kind of asymptotic relation. However, the sequence soon begins growing *extremely* rapidly, with $k_{10}$ in the neighborhood of $10^{36}$, and this rapid increase makes it a bit harder to get accurate estimates on $k$. Could anyone here point me in the right direction for how to do that? I'm especially interested in an *upper* bound on the terms. I'm not really looking for a full solution, just a few ideas for me to push off of.

Thanks in advance everybody!

Comment: I don't get it: given any $n$, you define the sequence member $\beta_n$ i.t.o. $k_n$. This, in turn, is supposedly the *largest number divisible by $n$* which clearly does not exist. I'm clearly missing s'thing.

Comment: No, It's defined so $\beta$ as large as possible, which means $k$ is as small as possible. $k$ is an integer, but $\beta$ is a non-integer rational.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Am I right in saying that `$\beta_n = 1/k_n$, with $k_n$ the smallest integer divisible by $n$?' If I am, then $k_n=n$ or - if you want to exclude that case - $k_n=2n$ by the prime decomposition theorem. (This last one agree w/ your three examples.) If I am not, my excuses - I had a very long day :).

Comment: Not quite--that breaks the requirement that the sum of the terms is less than one. 1/2+1/4+1/6=11/12, and so $\beta_4$=1/16, because 1/12 would make the sum equal 1.

Comment: Oh I finally see! You build the sequence recursively, incorporating the boundedness-by-one condition at each step. Sorry, I should have gotten that much earlier.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly! And don't worry about it, I can see how the wording would get confusing.

Comment: @automaton3: I have edited the text to embody the clarifications elicited by your comments.